# Is there a method like GetDeviceDescriptorPtr() in Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, usb, iokit

There is a function GetConfigurationDescriptorPtr, for getting pointer to configuration descriptor, inside IOUSBDeviceInterface. Link for reference is given below.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOUSBLib_h/Classes/IOUSBDeviceInterface/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/com/intfm/IOUSBDeviceInterface/GetConfigurationDescriptorPtr

Is there any such function like GetDeviceDecriptorPtr for getting pointer to device descriptor?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function, but we can create such function when we study the source code of USBProber.

Here is link to download the source code of IOUSBFamily, with USBProber inside it. http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/IOUSBFamily/